# i18next with multiple HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, locale, i18next

I have a webpage, that consits of many HTML pages linked with anchor tags. For the translations of this page i use i18next. In every page the translations seem to work, but the problem is, that after i have changed the language, and move to a different page, the selected language is not applied, and is set to default again. I have read about sessionStorage, as it could possibly solve this problem, but can not seem to implement it. 
js for switching languages:

```
function changeLanguageManual (lang) {
if (lang) {
    i18next.changeLanguage(lang);

}
jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
$('body').localize();
```

}

basically i want to achieve that when i navigate to a different inner HTML page, the selected language remains the same, and is not set to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation for `i18next` states that `changeLanguage` is an async method (returns a Promise). Try to invoke the `jQuery` `i18` `init` inside the callback.

```
i18next.changeLanguage('en', (err, t) => {
    if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
    jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
    $('body').localize();
});
```

Comment: I copied this script inside my i18next.js file, and it seems to work fine until i try to change the language again. Since the same js file is imported in all of the HTML pages, it always initializes the first language provided. Is there any way of achieving that the language selected in one page remains the same for others?

Comment: Yes, you can google about SessionStorage and LocalStorage. All pages of the same domain can store and read from the same instance of Session or Local storage